# Unable to get Angular Factory Data into Controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Trying to get data from a Factory and pass it into a controller to then be used in an ng-repeat. Not sure why, but the controller never runs the function established in the factory.

**Controller**

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('AppController',['$scope','ItemsFactory',
  function($scope,ItemsFactory){
    ItemsFactory.getItems(function(err, data){
      $scope.items = data;
      console.log('controller items', $scope.items);
    });
}]);
```

**Factory**

```
angular.module('myApp').factory('ItemsFactory', function($http){
    var getItems = function(){
      $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'js/data/data.min.json'
      }).then(function success(response, data){
        var results = response.data;
        console.log('factory results', results);
      }, function error(response){
        console.log('error getting items');
      });
    };
    return{
      getItems: getItems
    };
});
```

Followed a few other examples posted but nothing seems to work either

- [inject factory data into controller angular.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37495946/inject-factory-data-into-controller-angular-js)
- [Service process http.get results into new array and return to calling controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31624333/service-process-http-get-results-into-new-array-and-return-to-calling-controller)
- [inject factory data into controller angular.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37495946/inject-factory-data-into-controller-angular-js)

Results are returned by the factory, just unable to pass that through to the controller

**Edit**

Sincerely thank you everyone for your answers as they were all extremely useful, worked and shed a lot of light on promises and callbacks.

Decided to use @Fernando Fabreti answer as it was as close to what I was looking for as possible.

**Factory**

```
angular.module('myApp').factory('ItemsFactory', function($http){
    var getItems = function(callback){
      $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'js/data/data.min.json'
      }).then(function success(response, data){
        var results = response.data;
        if(callback) callback(null, results);
      }, function error(response){
        console.log('error getting items');
      });
    };
    return{
      getItems: getItems
    };
});
```

**Controller**

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('AppController',['$scope','ItemsFactory',
  function($scope, ItemsFactory){

    ItemsFactory.getItems(function(err, data){
      $scope.items = data;
      console.log('controller items', $scope.items);
    });
}]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define a callback param and "call" the callback once you get the results:

```
angular.module('myApp').factory('ItemsFactory', function($http){
    var getItems = function(cback){
      $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'js/data/data.min.json'
      }).then(function success(response, data){
        var results = response.data;
        console.log('factory results', results);
        if (cback) cback(null, results); 
      }, function error(response){
        console.log('error getting items');
        if (cback) cback(response, null);
      });
    };
    return{
      getItems: getItems
    };
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, getting confused on the Callbacks and Promises.

Comment: Much cleaner using the `$http` promise

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing up callback and promise styles of calling the method here.  You seem to want to pass a callback into getItems (getItems takes no parameter) and use a promise based result from the factory (though you return no promise).

Decide what you want to do. If you want to use the promise form do something like this (for simplicity sake):

```
   var getItems = function(){
      return $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'js/data/data.min.json'
      })
    };
```

And in your controller do something with the then or error function.

```
ItemsFactory.getItems().then(function(response) {
    $scope.items = response.data;
})
.catch(function(response) {
    console.error('error', response.status, response.data);
})
```

Comment: I see what you're saying

Comment: and can shorten it to ... `return $http.get('js/data/data.min.json');`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using callbacks, you should use the promise returned from `$http`. Simple return the result of `$http()` and you will be able to call `.then()` from that to get the data.

Factory:

```
angular.module('myApp').factory('ItemsFactory', function($http){
    var getItems = function(){
      return $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'js/data/data.min.json'
      }).then(function success(response){
        return response.data;
      }, function error(response){
        console.log('error getting items');
      });
    };
    return{
      getItems: getItems
    };
});
```

Controller:

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('AppController',['$scope','ItemsFactory',
  function($scope,ItemsFactory){
    ItemsFactory.getItems().then(function (data) {
         $scope.items = data;
    });
}]);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, combining what both you and @Robert Moskal makes sense. I did try it out as well and worked correctly and helping me to understand the whole callback and promises.